# How to force Windows 10 "Reset this PC"

Tags: windows-10, system-restore

I want to reset my PC, but when I click the "Get started" button in the settings under the "Reset this PC", nothing happens... I've found that this button activates the C:\Windows\System32\systemreset.exe file, so I've tested the file directly, as administrator, and still nothing happended. I tried restarting in the advanced startup to reset my PC from there, and when I click on the button (in the advanced startup menu), still nothing happended, my PC just started normally...

How can I force Windows to start the resetting process ?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the reset?  Do you want to keep files or just completely reset?

Comment: Just completely reset, but I don't have the Windows 10 installation files, this is an upgrade from Windows 8.1

Comment: The Windows 10 ISO for a clean install can be downloaded using Microsoft's [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). Maybe this is what you need?

Comment: But if I use this, will the new installation be activated ? I have a Windows 8.1 key, but not a Windows 10 key

Comment: One of the options when using the Media Tool is to upgrade the PC the tool is running on.  I know during the Free Upgrade period it would inherit the key from the machine, but I don't think that is the case anymore.  It looks like you need to buy a Windows 10 Key now according to [these instructions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10/) (expand the Using the tool to upgrade this PC to Windows 10 section)

Comment: Once the W10 free upgrade is activated you can reinstall for free anytime, it will automatically activate after re-installation. Windows activation servers store you hardware profile and key when you activate the first time, then after reinstall it will check for you hardware profile and activate automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your answers :) I used the Media Creation Tool like @Hexaholic suggested, and W10 was activated when I checked after the first startup.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference if it wasn't solved. Open powershell or cmd with admin and simply type systemreset.exe and press enter. This forces the OS to run the file whereas simply clicking on it, even a right click and run as admin, won't necessarily do that, especially with AV (though AV rarely effects system files, its not unheard of.)

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this behaviour when I logged on to the computer with the (domain) administrator account.

The reset options worked fine after I logged on with another account.

Comment: Actually, this might be something. If there was an issue with the user account the reset was tried from, creating a new user account and logging in with it could allow the system to work. I've experienced similar issues with Win10 myself, not with resets, but with other aspects, and creating a different user allowed me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For ASUS Transformer T100 TA Win 10: While holding down F9 key, Press & Hold down the Power key until "Wait a minute" shows up: This Boots into Windows
recovery mode with options to completely Reset to factory or Refresh. Do
not need Password (I had forgotten mine).

Comment: Do you know how "universal" this behavior is?  The OP doesn't mention brand or model.

Answer (score -2):

Run this script https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Remove-Local-Windows-57098b6c#content

I find the same error usually blocks secpol and gpedit from running unless opened from an administrator command prompt

Comment: Welcome to SU! Please clarify your answer a bit further and include your answer here (with credit) in case the link goes dead. Thanks!